# Search data from different sheet and show the results in sheet 1 (search using specific text)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'd like to ask for help on how to get the data from sheet 1 and get the data from Sheet 2 Column A  and view the results in Sheet 1 column B, looking or searching the first 3 char/digit. I have more than 15000 data in Sheet1 col A and my around 100 selection (type) in sheet 2. How to do this using macro..?

```
Example 
Sheet1                                  on sheet 2
Number (Col A) | Type (column B)           Col A   |  Col B (Type)
A112XXX2           Engine1                 A112XXX2   Engine1
B112AA12           ??                      B333QWE1   Engine2
B222VXX2           ??                      C000XXX2   Engine3
B333QWE1           ??                      Z312VVV9   Engine10
.
.
```

Basically using the first 4 Chars/digit (say A112 as my critera) in Sheet1 Col A is found on Sheet2 column A then  the data will appear in Sheet1 column-B  (type)

Thank you and appreciate you help.
wezzer

Comment: You can use a formula in sheet1 column B to do this: `=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A:A,4)&"*",Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)` no need for VBA here.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use VBA, it would be something around these lines:

```
Sub Find()
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, lRow2 As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 To lRow
    For i = 1 To lRow2
        If Left(sht.Cells(j, 1).Value, 4) = Left(sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value, 4) Then
            sht.Cells(j, 2).Value = sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

As Peh mentioned you can do it with a formula, but that could end up with bad performances considering the amount of datasets.

Comment: (1) `i` and `j` should be declared as `Long`; use `Option Explicit`. (2) I know you just want to help, but I'm not sure if it is a good idea to feed all those people asking for code without trying themselves.

Comment: @Peh, the vblookup is working great, thanks for your time. The reason I need to use it on macro because, the document has existig macro to import the data from a txt file. so when the data imported in sheet-1, I want to have a separate button to fill the sheet1-col B. or maybe include it on the existing macro..